# I am using Hamachi and tlauncher to play with my friends. But if I quit the game thr server gets closed. How do i leave and still my friends can play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi, minecraft-launcher

I found many things to play survival multiplayer but none worked except Hamachi. But if I am done and my friends aren't they also have to quit force fully because the server gets closed if I leave. We all play in tlauncher because we are kids and cannot afford the game. What can I do so that even if I quit the game my friends can still continue on Hamachi. Plsss I need this.

Comment: As you have stated that you cannot afford the game, you are committing piracy by using TLauncher without purchasing Minecraft. Therefore, Arqade is unable to provide assistance to you on the grounds that "site policies prohibit questions of the following types: ... Piracy, and support with pirated games." Please explore other avenues.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requests for support with pirated games are off topic.